# Condition checking in a for loop

Tags: c, for-loop, conditional-statements

Consider this code:

```
int main()
    {
        int i;
        int ints[3];
        ints[0] = 0;
        ints[1] = 1;
        ints[2] = 2;

        for(i = 0; (ints[i])<4 && i<3; i++)
        {
            printf("%d\n", ints[i]);
        }
    }
```

Is there a reason I shouldn't do this sort of conditioning in the loop? I mean, when `i` becomes `3`, will it look for a non-existing value at ints[3]? And if yes, is it ok?, since the loop is going to terminate anyway? It compiles and runs fine, but I was just wondering if there is some sort of a hidden problem with this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'for' keyword expands out the following way:

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    dothing();
```

becomes

```
    int i;

    i = 0; /* first part of (i = 0; ...) */
beginloop:
    if (i >= 2) goto endloop; /* second part of (...; i < 2; ...) */
    dothing();
    i++; /* final part of (...; ...; i++) */
    goto beginloop;
endloop:
```

So, your code would expand out as follows:

```
    i = 0;
beginloop:
    if (ints[i] >= 4)
        goto endloop;
    if (i >= 3)
        goto endloop;
    printf(...);
    i++;
    goto beginloop;
endloop:
```

While this is fine, there is a problem with the ordering of your tests:

```
(ints[i] < 4) && (i < 3)
```

You should always check array indexes first to ensure they are valid before using them:

```
i = 0:
    ints[0] < 4 && 0 < 3
i = 1:
    ints[1] < 4 && 1 < 3
i = 2:
    ints[2] < 4 && 2 < 3
i = 3:
    ints[3] < 4 && 3 < 3 /* illegal access to ints[3] */
```

As a general rule of thumb, always try to order your conditionals in order of cost unless there is a better reason for the ordering, such as priority: In this case, `i < 3` is the cheaper of the two tests, plus it is a constraint on the elements of `ints` you can access, so you checking the index should have a higher priority - you should check it before using it to tests `ints[i]` for anything.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, I initially did place  i<3 condition first, but intentionally swapped them to ask this question. I guess my real question was 'are the '&&' conditional statements always checked first to last and whether the checking terminates right after one of the conditions is false.'

Comment: To that last - they follow traditional C short-circuit rules; when C is evaluating logical expressions, `(x == 2 && y == 3) || (z == 1)`, it attempts to do the minimal work necessary; so if x is 1, it does not check y, but it does test z; if x is 2 and y is 3, it does not check z, but if x is 2 and y is 4, it checks x, y and z.

Answer (score 4):

In the last iteration of this loop, the expression `ints[i]<4` will access `ints[3]`. Since this access reads past the end of the array `ints`, the behavior is undefined in C. So yes, this is not good code. It may work most of the time, but the behavior is ultimately undefined.

Comment: As Matt stated, this behavior is undefined in C.  So it would depends on how your compiler would handle this sequence of code.  At my last place of employment, we wrote some C for 16 bit systems, and the particular compiler we used had an array size limit.  However, the way that compiler worked, we could malloc two arrays next to each other, and the pointer of the first would spill over into the second after reaching the size limit.  Not really what you want to do unless you absolutely have to do it and there is no way around it.

Comment: What is I swap the statements around like the another answer suggested? Would that still not be safe? Are the '&&' conditions checked necessarily from first to last or is it compiler-dependent?//edit: posted it not seeing the previous comment, which sort of answers this one.

Comment: If you swap the statements, then the code is safe. `&&` is a short-circuiting operator in C. The condition `i < 3` becomes false before the to access `ints[3]`; the loop terminates immediately after `i < 3` evaluates to false. Thus, all the accesses to `ints[]` are inside the array, and the behavior is defined. Whether or not the code is clear & maintainble is another matter.

Comment: Just want to add to this answer:
The rule of thumb is to avoid undefined behavior like a plague unless your specific compiler has a defined outcome for that AND you have a **very good** reason to do so.

Comment: The && operator does one hundred percent reliable perform the first test, and if that test is false, not do the second test at all.

Answer (score 3):

It will be better to do `i < 3 && ints[i] < 4` because the second part of the statement is evaluated only if the first one is true.  The way you have it, it will look for `ints[3]` that does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't okay to do this, because `ints[3]` will indeed be accessed. Now, because this is C, you're not going to get an error (unfortunately), but you'll never know for sure what the outcome would be.

Swapping the statements will solve the problem, because the && operator is optimized so that it doesn't evaluate the second condition if the first one is false.

Answer (score 1):

The way you have written the loop, your code will try to read the non-existing array element ints [3]. That's undefined behaviour; a consequence is that *anything* can happen. Right now the whole internet is in uproar because of some code in OpenSSL that invoked undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

The loop terminates, that's okay. But you're accessing an area outside of what you're allowed to. It is undefined behaviour. You may get a segmentation anytime. But you're lucky.

Try putting `i<3` before. That would work just fine.

```
for(i = 0; i<3 && (ints[i])<4; i++)
```

If `i` becomes `3`, the second part is not evaluated. See [short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).